# How to do doubles?

Tags: practice, drums

Is there a "by the book" way to do doubles, or is this something that different people will simply interpret (and execute) in different ways? I understand that both strokes with each hand should sound the same, but depending on how you do them, they'll feel very different.

Here are the 3 ways of doing doubles I identified:

1. 2 exact same strokes in terms of feel (to me this seems ok at lower speeds, but seems limiting (and I might be wrong here) after you reach higher speeds)
2. Utilizing the bounce - I guess this would be some sort of hit and then push with fingers right after the bounce
3. Push-pull - normal stroke, followed by a second hit that's done with fingers right after the bounce from the first stroke and while your hand is going up (this to me seems like the way to go at higher speeds)

Of course it depends on the situation and the drum kit piece (option 3) might not work best with a floor tom) but is any of these the "standard way" doubles should be practiced? Thanks.

Comment: To me it's mostly 2 except I'm pushing down on the stick before the first hit but not pushing so hard it won't bounce. The harder I push, the shorter the time between the first and the second hits. Then I have to lift immediately to avoid a third hit. I'm only an advanced beginner so just commenting what I do.

Comment: I think you are describing the stages that you will go through. As your become experienced. You are supposed to star with number 1 to reinforce that each stroke is clear and loud as you porgress number 2 becomes the norm with doubles also with 3. 4. 5 strokes rolls. number 3 is a way to describe the Mueller technique that is helpful building your speed.

Answer (score 1):

I know a trick for pllaying high-speed triplets in which you whip down with one hand, the other hand taps to create a ghost and then the first hand pulls backwards with a hit. I'm guessing that this technique could be used without the ghost. The timing would be hard at first but after it had been mastered it could be used to get to very high speeds. If you were to compare it with one of the three that you have mentioned than I would say that it is most similar to 3 but isn't exactly as you have described.